Include kustomization yaml file in other customization file
I have a kustomization file that contains a lot of patches by target:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ../../base
patches:
  - path: configmap-overlay.yml
  - path: deploy-overlay.yml

  - target:
      labelSelector: domain=xyz
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /some/path1
        value: val1
  - target:
      kind: Deployment
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /some/path2
        value: val2
  - target:
      kind: Service
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /some/path3
        value: val3

... a lot more

Would it be possible to group the target patches in a separate kustomization file and refer to the file from the above kustomization snippet, instead of having them all in a single file?

It's possible you could solve this through the use of a "component"; see my answer to another question that might be relevant.
